# Prevent Open URL Redirect from gorilla/mux

Tags: go, redirect, gorilla, go-http

I am working on a RESTful web application using Go + gorilla/mux v1.4 framework. Some basic security testing after a release revealed an [Open URL Redirection](https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00500100_open-redirection-reflected) vulnerability in the app that allows user to submit a specially crafted request with an external URL that causes server to response with a 301 redirect.

I tested this using [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) and found that any request that redirects to an external URL in the app seems to be responding with a 301 Moved Permanently. I've been looking at all possible ways to intercept these requests before the 301 is sent but this behavior seems to [be baked into the net/http server implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2344).

Here is the raw request sent to the server (myapp.mycompany.com:8000):

```
GET http://evilwebsite.com HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: myapp.mycompany.com:8000
Content-Length: 0
```

And the response any time is:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://evilwebsite.com/
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2020 08:55:24 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Despite putting in checks for the request.URL to prevent this type of redirect in the http.handler, I haven't had any luck getting the request to reach the handler. It appears that the base http webserver is performing the redirect without allowing it to reach my custom handler code as defined in the PathPrefix("/").Handler code.

My goal is to ensure the application returns a 404-Not Found or 400-Bad Request for such requests. Has anybody else faced this scenario with gorilla/mux. I tried the same with a Jetty web app and found it returned a perfectly valid 404. I've been at this for a couple of days now and could really use some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the claimed Open URL redirect security issue. This request is invalid in that the path contains an absolute URL with a different domain than the `Host` header. No sane client (i.e. browser) can be lured into issuing such an invalid request in the first place and thus there is no actual attack vector.

Sure, a custom client could be created to submit such a request. But a custom client could also be made to interpret the servers response in a non-standard way or visit a malicious URL directly without even contacting your server. This means in this case the client itself would be the problem and not the servers response.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for the clarification. However, I'm still looking to get gorilla/mux to return a 404 like Jetty when confronted with such a peculiar request. Should I switch away from gorilla/mux and roll with something else?

Comment: @CodeManure: you can probably use [SkipClean](https://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.SkipClean) to stop the automatic redirect and then deal with the invalid path in your own handler. But again, this is no open redirect issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Setting `SkipClean(true)` on the base router did the trick! Appreciate your help!